# FFmpeg for Windows Phone development

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, ffmpeg, sharpffmpeg

I have used FFmpeg in ASP.Net web-based applications. Now I want to use it for Windows Phone development.

Is it possible to use it? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg is not supported on Windows Phone 7 at all and, as far as I could find it on the web, there is no port to Windows Phone 8. Windows Phone 7 never supported native code which was introduced back in Windows Phone 8.

Apparently it is not possible to compile it for Windows Phone 8 and heavy investment must be made.

If you want to play video files, you can do it with the `MediaElement` control. You can read more about it here: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Video_Playback_with_MediaElement_in_Windows_Phone.